# HeroKu - Gradle SpringBoot - H14 Error Deployment

Tags: java, web, heroku, deployment

I recently run into an "H14 Error" While Trying To Deploy Gradle Spring Project into the HeroKu platform.

Error:

code=H14 desc="No web processes running"

In My Project Folder, I have a "Procfile"

```
web: java -jar build/server/webapp-runner-*.jar build/libs/*.war
web: java -jar target/ClockGUI-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

I have researched many solutions but not worked out.

Please help me. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two issues with your `Procfile`:

- **You can't declare two `web` processes.**

  What command runs your web server? That's the only one that should be declared this way.

  (I'm not sure what `ClockGUI-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` is supposed to be, but assuming "GUI" means something like SWT, Swing, or JavaFX, it won't work on Heroku. Where would the interface appear?)
- **You've included a Heroku CLI command.**

  `heroku ps:scale web=1` is a command that you might run locally to scale your application's web dynos. It's not something that should be baked into the application source code.

  Consider an e-commerce application. At certain times of the year, you might see a spike in traffic. You could use this command to scale up additional web dynos to handle the load. That doesn't (and shouldn't) require redeploying the application.

  Remove that line. It doesn't do anything in the `Procfile` anyway.

Commit the updated `Procfile` and redeploy. Then, if you don't have any web dynos running, run `heroku ps:scale web=1` in a terminal, ideally from your project directory so Heroku can infer which app you want to scale.